# Cannot play movie with QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

I try to play movie with Qt5 on OS X El Capitan v10.11.6.
I use QMediaPlayer, QMediaPlaylist, and QVideoWidget to play.

Write source code as same as Qt's documentation, but it show only black window and not play any movie.

Here is my source code.

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainwindow;
    mainwindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

class QMediaPlayer;
class QMediaPlaylist;
class QVideoWidget;

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);

private:
    QMediaPlayer* player;
    QMediaPlaylist* playlist;
    QVideoWidget* videoWidget;
};

#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QVideoWidget>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
    videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;

    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

    playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("box.mp4"));

    videoWidget->show();
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
    player->play();

    QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(videoWidget);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

I check "box.mp4" exists in the same directory.

Where is problem? How should I fix source code to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `box.mp4` in the binaries directory? Try running this program in command line and see if there is some output.

Comment: add complete path

Comment: @Shmuel H: Run program in command line, but get same output.

Comment: @eyllanesc: rewrite file path to full path, I can play mp4! thank you.

Comment: write the solution in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify media file path to full path in `mainwindow.cpp`.

Before

```
playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("box.mp4"));
```

After

```
playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path/to/box.mp4"));
```